# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in AngularJS on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, visual-studio, internet-explorer

Symptoms:

When loading AngularJS in Visual Studio 2015 through an intranet url, an error is thrown in the AngularJS library at this point:

```
    line 7:       if(H(b)||Ta(b))
```

(for angularjs.min.js)

```
    line 322:     } else if (isArray(obj) || isArrayLike(obj)) {
```

(for angularjs.js)

In my case, this is when I have a second local site configured, "localhost-alternative" on 127.0.0.1. Why does Internet Explorer show this error? It works fine in Chrome, Edge or Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, the browser does not regognise it is on your local PC. It reverts to intranet settings. When Internet Explorer thinks you're browsing your Intranet, it reverts to the IE7 rendering engine. And Angular does not speak prehistoric very well.

Resolution?

You can send some custom headers with each response. You can do this adding them to your web.config, like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
              ....
```

This header instructs Internet Explorer to use its current rendering engine, so AngularJS will render like it should.